# how to update database column if valuenot exist in database

Tags: android

im creating an application which update database it any column change innection with database below is my code ijust want to check if any column check then insert into database helpme how do i do that?? i want to update database table name"uss_school" it have 8 column all are text field just tel me for testing how to add dummy data on that table? i dont want to delete and fil again table i only want to insert if column not exist in database  how to update table?? see screeenshot http://imgur.com/QkKk1r8 below is my query for select now i want tp update database for table"uss_school" plz put 1 row with dummy data

```
     public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.schoollunchapp/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "YummiSlice.sqlite";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 
private SQLiteDatabase myData; 

private final Context myContext;

public DataBase(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}   
/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }else{  
        CopyFiles();
    }
}

private void CopyFiles()
{
    try
    { 
       InputStream is = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME); 
       File outfile = new File(DB_PATH,DB_NAME);
       outfile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
       outfile.createNewFile();

      if (is == null)
      throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
      else
      {
         FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outfile);      
      // BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream( new         
         FileOutputStream(outfile));
          byte buf[] = new byte[128];
            do {
          int numread = is.read(buf);
                if (numread <= 0)
                    break;
          out.write(buf, 0, numread);
           } while (true);

            is.close();
            out.close();
      }
       //AssetFileDescriptor af = am.openFd("world_treasure_hunter_deluxe.apk");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
          throw new RuntimeException(e); 
    }

}    

 /**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the  
        application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
 private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

    }

    if(checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
 @SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

 }

 public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
  String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

 }

 @Override
public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}


   //---retrieve records---
  public Cursor selectQuery(String query) throws SQLException 
 {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myData = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    Cursor mCursor =myData.rawQuery(query, null);
    mCursor.moveToFirst();      
    myData.close();

    return mCursor;
 }


 ////////// For Insert And Update Data ////////
 public void insert_update(String query) throws SQLException 
 {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myData = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    myData.execSQL(query);
    myData.close();        
 }




  }



             DataBase db;
             public class MealGroups  extends Activity {
              @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mealsgroups);
        db = new DataBase(getBaseContext()); 
      try {
            db.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }




                mma = new mealgroupscreenadapter(this);
    new getDataTask().execute();

    listmealsgroups.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent iMenuList = new Intent(MealGroups.this, MenuGroup.class);

            iMenuList.putExtra("meal_groupname",
                    Category_name.get(position));

            iMenuList.putExtra("Meal_groupid", Category_ID.get(position));

            iMenuList.putExtra("id", schedule_id);
            iMenuList.putExtra("title", semestertitle);
            iMenuList.putExtra("startdate", start_date);
            iMenuList.putExtra("enddate", end_date);

            iMenuList.putExtra("SchoolLevelId", SchoolLevelId);

            iMenuList.putExtra("School_ID", School_ID);

            iMenuList.putExtra("School_name", School_name);

            startActivity(iMenuList);

        }
    });

}

public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

    getDataTask() {
        if (!prgLoading.isShown()) {
            prgLoading.setVisibility(0);

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        displayData();
        return _response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        prgLoading.setVisibility(8);
        // pleaseselect.setVisibility(0);
        if ((Category_ID.size() > 0)) {
            listmealsgroups.setVisibility(0);
            listmealsgroups.setAdapter(mma);
            mma.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } else {
            listmealsgroups.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            NoMenuAvailable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            NoMenuAvailable
                    .setText("No Meal Group Available for this School.");
        }

    }
}

private void displayData() {

    Cursor mCursor2 = db
            .selectQuery("SELECT DISTINCT WHERE s.school_id ='"
                    + School_ID + "'");
    Category_ID.clear();
    Category_name.clear();

    if (mCursor2.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            Category_ID.add(mCursor2.getString(mCursor2
                    .getColumnIndex("meal_group_id")));

            Category_name.add(mCursor2.getString(mCursor2
                    .getColumnIndex("title")));

        } while (mCursor2.moveToNext());
    }

    mCursor2.close();

}

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Like This.

Update uss_school set information='testing' where **information is null**

Comment: suppose in my uss+school table have 18 entries  with id 1 to 18 now i want to update 2 new data with id 4 and 19 so how i will do that? i want total number of entries are 19    if id already exist just replace data other wise add new entry

Comment: 1. Run the query: select count(id) from uss_school 2.check whether the count value>0 or not, if yes(Already data available) then write update query else(no data with that id) write insert query.